# Nextjs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 on production server with nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js, http-status-code-404, vps

My app is building and deploying correctly locally, no errors at all whatsoever. However, when deployed on the server, I get a bunch of net::ERR_ABORTED 404 for every static file attempted to be accessed at /_next/static/. The pages html and content is still displayed, but css, build manifest, and all other files in static throw this 404 right away.

So far I've tried a few things. I read it could be due to dynamic routing and use of Link, so I stripped the app down to anchors to get rid of routes and Link modules, but it's still not loading properly. Playing with the nginx config hasn't helped much either. I'm using nginx, proxied / to open up at port 8082, and location /_next/static/ with alias /var/www/website/.next/static/

Someone suggested getting rid of the last slashes, but that changes nothing. Sister website on 8081 has got the same config and it is working properly, no display issues at all. I took that one down to see if it was some conflict with it, but the one at 8082 still throws the same 404 errors. Here is the config I've got there:

```
//at /etc/nginx/sites-available/website                                                                                                    

server {
        server_name website.domain

        gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_min_length 256;

        location /_next/static/ {
                alias /var/www/website/.next/static/;
                expires 365d;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


}
```

Any clues on what could possibly be causing the 404s? Thank you in advance!

**Update:** For the sake of trying, I uploaded the sister site on 8081 to the 8082 directory, and it is working well. That tells us it's not an nginx config error but something in the nextjs code within the other app that's causing troubles. Here is the `package.json` of the app:

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^12.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-sound": "^1.2.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.5.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.4",
    "solc": "^0.8.9",
    "web3": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

From this I also tried removing url-loader and the next.config.js from it, which is handling some music files, and instead set all music in the public folder, but it's still not working without it. All of the other dependencies are in the other app too, the one that works well. Is there anything that I should particularly be looking at in my code that might cause troubles with paths at build?

Comment: Could you pleae share what finally worked? You mention you updated some url in the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a proper idiot. I was forgetting to restart nginx so that the config got updated when making changes to it. Of course, nothing was displayed properly since the file wasn't updated and the correct paths weren't being taken into account. All working properly now.

Lesson learned: Make sure to always restart your server after any changes you make.